# creating a list of anonymous type and passing to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

i want to to display all items from my parent table with selected items from child table and create a list of them to pass to my view.

## Here is my action method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    List<EmployeeAtt> empWithDate = new List<EmployeeAtt>();
    var employeelist = _context.TblEmployee.ToList();

    foreach (var employee in employeelist)
    {
        // var employeeAtt = new EmployeeAtt();
        var employeeAtt = _context.AttendanceTable
            .GroupBy(a => a.DateAndTime.Date)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Date = g.Key,
                Emp_name = employee.EmployeeName,
                InTime = g
                    .Where(e => e.ScanType == "I")
                    .Min(e => e.DateAndTime.TimeOfDay),
                OutTime = g
                    .Where(e => e.ScanType == "O")
                    .Max(e => e.DateAndTime.TimeOfDay),
            });
    }
    return View();
}
```

## Here is my view

```
 @model IEnumerable<Attendance.Models.EmployeeAtt>
    @{`enter code here`
        ViewBag.Title = "AttendanceTable";
        <!--Get number of days of current month-->
        var DaysInmonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
        <!--Create a CurrentName field-->
        var CurrentName = "";
    }

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmpName</th>
                <!--Loop all the days of month and print it-->
                @for (var numb = 1; numb <= DaysInmonth; numb++)
                {
                    <th>@numb</th>
                }

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Loop model-->
            @foreach (var emp in Model)
            {
                //if Name is repeated, skip
                if (CurrentName != emp.Emp_name)
                {
                    // Set Name
                    CurrentName = emp.Emp_name;
            <tr>
                <!--print employee name one time only at the start of row-->
                <td>@emp.Emp_name</td>

                <!--loop all days of month-->
                @for (var numb = 1; numb <= DaysInmonth; numb++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @{
                            <!--print only that date time value which is equal to current date(as it will match column header) and current employee name, else print empty-->
                            var GetThatDayValue = Model.Where(a => a.Date.Value.Day == numb && a.Emp_name == emp.Emp_name).FirstOrDefault();
                            var DD = GetThatDayValue != null ? GetThatDayValue.InTime + " " + GetThatDayValue.OutTime : "A";
                            <text> @DD </text>
                        }
                    </td>    
            }
            </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can i convert from anonymous type to concrete type so that i can make a list of view model objects ( EmployeeAtt) and access it in my view

Comment: Don't use `Select(x => new {}` if you don't want anonymous types

Comment: You cannot do that because the type you are passing to your view and the type in your view are not the same. Create a class that has all the things required to satisfy your view's needs. This will be the Model you will pass to your view. In your controller get the stuff from the database and create instances of the Model. In your view make sure to change the model to this new type you created so they agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the creation of anonymous objects if you can just select concrete type at the compile time?

So basically you may do this in Select:

```
.Select(g => new EmployeeAtt { /* fill in properties */ });
```

If you do not know exact type and want to convert in runtime you may try to use `Convert.ChangeType` along with `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`

```
Convert.ChangeType(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(objectType).ConvertFrom(anonymousObject), objectType));
```

Comment: i have added my viewmodel name (EmployeeAtt) as you told. but now how can i create a list of viewmodel objects which i want to use in my view and how to send this list from controller to view ... return view (?)

Comment: Well you already have `empWithDate` so just copy there new values in your loop by calling `empWithDate.AddRange(/* your LINQ goes here*/)` then just pass this variable to the view: `return View(empWithDate)`

Comment: empWithDate.AddRange(?); what LINQ query i will use inside AddRange()

Comment: You may use your existing LINQ directly in that call or you may call AddRange with `employeeAtt` variable as a parameter which probably will be a better and cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks i added like this  empWithDate.AddRange(employeeAtt); but my results are not according to what i need. i want to get against each employee his  first time with "I" as InTime and last time with "O" as OutTime but what i am getting against each employee is same time . how to fix this now